# Meaning of "then" in this context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> These types of “approaches to research are really useful when either
> people don’t care about what you’re asking, or they post-rationalise
> to a degree that basically starts to make no sense,” says Smith. “So
> when you’re asking people about different packaging variations on a
> bottle of bleach, nobody really cares. And **then** you ask people in a
> group setting, and you listen to somebody who sounds as though they’ve
> got a bit of gravitas, they’ll go with that opinion, because they
> didn’t really have one in the first place.”

I'd like to know whether bolded 'then' mean 'afterward' or not.
If not what do you think it means?

Comment: First you do one thing, **then** you do another, but in this context it is used to compare two different situations. Similarly: "I think it is this, but then again, it could be that."

Comment: There's a sense of consequentiality as well as mere sequentiality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there appears to be a relation between the reactions from people being talked about first and from people mentioned next, this use of "then" seems to aim at expressing an additional sort of context and would mean "in addition", "and also".

From *SOED*

> **then**     **2b** In the next place, next, esp. in a series or narrative; in addition, and also, besides.